# Pass an array to an array member of undeclared size of a class

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to have an array whose values be declared from main to a class. Here's the sample code.

```
class test{
public:
      const double arr[];
};

int main(){

     test t;
     t.arr[] = {1, 2};
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to intialize in the main it gives me an error **error:unexpected expression.**

But if I remove the `t.arr[]` in main, it compiles fine.

Comment: `const double arr[];` is "unexpected" as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. `const double arr[];` - variable length array? [Invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c).
2. `t.arr[]` - invalid syntax (`operator[]` call with no arguments?), `arr` is also `const` and you can't assign to any arrays.

But you can do [aggregate intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
class test {
public:
    const double arr[2]; // fixed size
};

int main() {

    test t = {{1, 2}}; // not an assignment
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just realized, perhaps I should have given it as (t.arr)[], which sounds more reasonable. I didn't understand why it compiles first off, if a variable binned array is given.